# Using getline to read from file to a 2d string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file-io, text-files

I am trying to read the contents of a text file into a 2D string array, but no matter what I have tried or searched, I can not find a solution. The code is supposed to load a text file separate it into elements by finding horizontal tabs and display the output. When I run the code as is, I receive an error that I found out from searching online, means that I'm trying to manipulate memory I shouldn't be. I'm not asking for the code to be written, just a push in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

this is what I get when I run the program:

```
0x23fd5c

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.344 s
Press any key to continue.
```

EDIT:: I have corrected the code so it now functions as it should, but it is not storing the last entry of each line in the text file correctly. I can somehow display the number 100 which is the last entry, but when I try to pass that location or display just playList[0][5] , it says it is equal to the first entry of the next line. Any help would be amazing I posted the current code below.

here is my code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <cstdlib>

 using namespace std;

 void readTextFile( int &Count, string playList[50][5]);
 void userAddition( int &Count, string playList[50][5]);




int main()
{
string decision;
string playList[50][5];
int Count = 0;
readTextFile(Count, playList);

cout << "If you would like to add to the list, Please enter 'Y'. If you would like to exit     
 please enter 'N'. ---->  ";
getline(cin, decision);
if (decision=="y" || decision=="Y")
    userAddition(Count, playList);
else
{
    return(0);
}

return 0;
} // End of Main FN.






void readTextFile( int &Count, string playList[50][5])
{

string inputfield;

ifstream infile("c:\\cTunes.txt", ifstream::in);
    if ( infile.is_open() )
    {
        // File is read.
    }   // end if
    else
    {
        cout << "Error Opening file" << endl;
        return; //Program Closes.
    }  // end else

    cout << setw(30)<<left<< "TITLE"<< setw(10) <<left<<"LENGTH"<<  
      // Outputs a title to          each column that is displayed.
    setw(40)<< left<<"ARTIST"<< setw(40) << left<<"ALBUM"<<
    setw(15) << left <<"GENRE" << setw(5) << left << "RATING" << endl;

getline(infile, inputfield, '\t');    // read until tab
while(! infile.eof())  // loop until file is no longer valid.
 {

        playList[Count][0] = inputfield;
        getline(infile, inputfield, '\t');           // read until tab.

        playList[Count][1] = inputfield;
        getline(infile, inputfield, '\t');             // read until tab.

        playList[Count][2] = inputfield;
        getline(infile, inputfield, '\t');           // read until tab.

        playList[Count][3] = inputfield;
        getline(infile, inputfield, '\t');          // read until tab.

        playList[Count][4] = inputfield;
        getline(infile, inputfield);                // read until end of line.
        playList[Count][5] = inputfield;

    cout << setw(30)<<left<< playList[Count][0] << setw(10) <<left<<playList[Count][1] <<          
    // Output the line number equal to count.
    setw(40)<< left<<playList[Count][2] << setw(40) << left<< playList[Count][3] <<
    setw(15) << left << playList[Count][4] << setw(5) << left << playList[Count][5] <<                     
    endl;

    /*cout <<"Title: " << setw(25)<<left<< playList[Count][0]<<endl;
    cout <<"Length: " << setw(5) <<left<<playList[Count][1] << endl;
    cout <<"Artist: " << setw(50)<< left<<playList[Count][2] << endl;
    cout <<"Album: " << setw(40) << left<< playList[Count][3] << endl;
    cout <<"Genre: " << setw(15) << left << playList[Count][4] << endl;
    cout <<"Rating: " << setw(5) << left << playList[Count][5] << endl<<endl;*/

    Count++;            // Increment counter by 1
    getline(infile, inputfield, '\t'); // read next line until tab.

    }    // end while
 infile.close(); // close the file being read from.
 cout<<endl<<endl<<playList[0][5]<<endl;
 } // End of readTextFile
```

I believe  getline is causing the problem when reading till the end of the line but I'm truly at a loss.

Comment: `string playList[19][5];` Why?! Why not use a `vector <vector <string> >`?

Comment: If you attached an example input + expected output, you would get answers more suitable to your specific situation.

Comment: Also note that when there was an error while opening the file: `else { cout << "Error Opening file" << endl; }` you should probably use `return` to prevent the rest of your function being executed.

Comment: The sample input would be from a text file, where the terms are delimited by a horizontal tab. There are five terms: Title,Length,Album,Genre,PlayCount. The program is supposed to read the text file put each term into the array and start on a new row when it reaches the end of the row. Right now im simply trying to fill the array and output it, to be sure it is filled correctly.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will add the return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that in the following line:

```
cout << playList << endl;
```

you are printing the address of the array, not the contents. you will need
a loop to print the contents.

Second, in the following code:

```
if ( infile.is_open() )
{
   // ok, read in the file
}    // end if
else
{
cout << "Error Opening file" << endl;
//a return statement is missing
}
```

you need a return statement to avoid reading from a closed stream (which can cause a crash)

Finally, your function does not return anything, so it should either be declared void
or return some value (in which there is no sense according to the context).

Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help. Would printing the address be giving me the error I posted above? When I run the code, windows prompts me to close the program, rather than the compiler, which leads me to believe Im accessing something I shouldn't be. I switched the function to void, and added a return in the error check.

Comment: It is hard to say because your code worked OK for me when I compiled
it using a minGW compiler, even before the fixes. Are you using 
visual studio?

Comment: I have tried both Visual Studio and CodeBlocks :-( . I have been trying for to get it to work for 6hrs. My only other thought is that my computer is not allowing the compiler to access the file.

Comment: The last try is if you can post a link to your input file. Maybe it magically causes your program to crash.
In any other way it is either OS related or compiler related. 
(Although codeblocks uses minGW I think)

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/playlist that is the link to the file. The name of the file is different from what is in my code because I was testing. I was able to display it finally but I am still getting the same error. I'm going to try to run in xCode now and see what happens.Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate the input.

Comment: Your input file causes it to crash :) 
Technically, it reads more than 19 entries that you gave your 2d array, it reads like 23, goes beyond the borders of the array and corrupts the machine stack. Why does it read 23 when there are 19 lines? 
Because you aren't reading a whole line from the file every loop iteration. e.g. you don't read the '100' in the first iteration.

If you are new to programming, a good suggestion is to add a lot 
of "cout" commands to print important stuff, like the "inputfield"
every time, so you can see what data your program is getting. Or run the debugger like I did

Comment: Ok, I understand what your saying. Thank you very much for your help and advice!

Comment: Here is your code with all the fixes I suggested and it works on your input file:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18936011/5647125632.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You are using `std::string` for storing the string, `std::ifstream` for reading from a file, `std::getline` for reading words... you should really use `std::vector`s instead of arrays:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> Line;
std::vector<Line> playList;
```

It will make things easier for you.
I also recommend you to change the way you read from a file to:

```
while(getline(...))
{
    ...
}
```

---

But since you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, your function could look like this:

```
// reads the content of input file and stores it into playList:
void readTextFile(std::ifstream& infile, std::string playList[][5])
{
    std::string line;
    for (int lineIndex = 0; getline(infile, line); ++lineIndex)
    {
        // skip empty lines:
        if (line.empty()) continue;

        std::string word;
        std::istringstream lineStream(line);
        for (int wordIndex = 0; getline(lineStream, word, '\t'); ++wordIndex)
        {
            // skip empty words:
            if (line.empty()) continue;

            playList[lineIndex][wordIndex] = word;
        }
    }
}
```

that could be used like this:

```
std::string playList[19][5];

std::ifstream infile("c:\\Test.txt");
if (infile.is_open())
{
    readTextFile(infile, playList);
    infile.close();
}
else
    std::cout << "Error Opening file" << std::endl;
```

Also note that `cout << playList << endl;` outputs the address of the first word. To print all words, you will have to write a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I am currently in a very basic C++ programming class and we have yet to cover vectors, so I don't think it will be acceptable for me to use them unfortunately.

Comment: @Davidtftyfy: Check my answer now :) Note that given solution relies on the fact that there are no more than 5 words within each line in the file.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try. Thank you for the time you put into that. I am amazed how helpful people are on this site, this is my first post so I didn't know what to expect.

Comment: @Davidtftyfy: You will get great answers on this site... The better the question is the better and more suitable answers you will get. Just read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and Skeet's article about [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The `readTextFile` function does not return anything. You need to return a string. If you are getting the error `what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid` then this is your problem. You can avoid similar problems by using `-Wall` compiler option.